How to turn off default ASP.NET MVC logger?
I have ASP.NET MVC application and I'm adding Serilog. Now I have logs both from Serilog and from default ASP.NET MVC logger. How to remove the second one?

System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Clear(); doesn't work


I'm using
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
                .CreateLogger();

SerilogWebClassic.Configure(cfg => cfg
   .UseLogger(Log.Logger)
);


Well, now I figured out that it's not some "default ASP.NET MVC logger" but IIS Express logs
